# Menu system in c

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement

I'm having serious trouble with my program it is supposed to provide a menu and do all the functions the code is pretty explanatory my problem is I only have visual studios which doesnt allow scanf and scanf_s and messes with things so I use online compilers but those are still iffy. Can any one help and give me some tips. I'm having trouble with the math and function to list accounts, some whiles are empty as well I wasn't sure if that was best to use. I'm relatively new to this forum. It also can't have struct and can only be in C :-(

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[20];
float avail_bal;

void options();
void open();
void list();
void deposit();
void withdraw();
void exit();

int main(void)
{
    char option;
    while(1){
        printf("****Banking System WELCOME****\n");
        printf("Enter 1-5 of the following options: \n");

        option = getchar();
        scanf("%c\n", &option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case '1': open();
            break;
            case '2': list();
            break;
            case '3': deposit();
            break;
            case '4': withdraw();
            break;
            case '5': return 0;
            default: exit();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void options()
{
printf("1. Open Account\n");
printf("2. List Accounts\n");
printf("3. Deposit\n");
printf("4. Withdraw\n");
printf("5. Exit");
}

void open()
{
    float avail_bal = 0;
    char name[20];
    int acc_num;

    printf("Open new account(enter number 1-5)\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &acc_num);
    printf("Account number:     %d\n");
    printf("Available balance:      %f\n");
}

void list()
{
}

void deposit()
{
float add;
int acc_num;

printf("Which count do you want to deposit money in?");
scanf(" %d", &acc_num);
printf("Amount to deposit: ");
scanf("%f", &add);
while()
{
}
}
void withdraw()
{
int acc_num;
float withdraw;

printf("Account to withdraw from: ");
scanf("%d", &acc_num);
printf("Amount to withdraw from account: ")
scanf("%f", &withdraw);
while()
{
    printf("Current balance for account %d: %f ");
    break;
} acc_num++
}
```

Comment: you should use different names for functions and variables.

Comment: For that matter, use different names than the standard library already reserves, like [`exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit)

Comment: there are many issues with this question, it'd be better if you narrow it down to one single issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `scanf` was interesting. Here is an example for how to do without (although you shouldn't) such that you can play with your code easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// only 5 accounts possible
int accounts[5];
// each its balance
float avail_bal[5];

void options();
// open(P) is a standard Posix function
void bopen();
void list();
void deposit();
void withdraw();
// exit(3) is a standard C function
void pexit();

int main(void)
{
  char option;
  while (1) {
    printf("****Banking System WELCOME****\n");
    printf("Enter 1-5 of the following options: \n");
    options();
    option = getc(stdin);
    // swallow the '\n'
    getc(stdin);
    switch (option) {
    case '1':
      bopen();
      break;
    case '2':
      list();
      break;
    case '3':
      deposit();
      break;
    case '4':
      withdraw();
      break;
    case '5':
      pexit();
    default:
      pexit();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void options()
{
  puts("1. Open Account");
  puts("2. List Accounts");
  puts("3. Deposit");
  puts("4. Withdraw");
  puts("5. Exit");
}

void bopen()
{
  int acc_num;
  char c;

  puts("Open new account(enter number 1-5)");
  c = getc(stdin);
  getc(stdin);
  // assuming ASCII here where the digits 0-9 start at place 48 in the table
  acc_num = (int) c - 48;
  if (acc_num < 1 || acc_num > 5) {
    puts("Account number must be between one and five inclusive");
    return;
  }
  if (accounts[acc_num] != 0) {
    printf("Account number %d is already taken\n", acc_num);
    return;
  }
  // mark account as taken
  accounts[acc_num] = 1;
  // spend a fiver for the new client for being a new client
  avail_bal[acc_num] = 5.0;
  printf("Account number:     %d\n", acc_num);
  printf("Available balance:      %f\n", avail_bal[acc_num]);
}

void list()
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (accounts[i] != 0) {
      printf("Account 000%d:  %f\n", i, avail_bal[i]);
    }
  }
}

void deposit()
{
  float add;
  int acc_num;
  char c;
  char s[100];

  puts("Which account do you want to deposit money in?");
  c = getc(stdin);
  getc(stdin);
  acc_num = (int) c - 48;
  printf("Amount to deposit: ");
  // to get a number without scanf() we have to read the input as a string
  // (fgets() adds a '\0' at the end, so keep a seat free for it)
  fgets(s, 99, stdin);
  // and convert it to a double (atof() only for brevity, use strtod() instead)
  add = atof(s);
  avail_bal[acc_num] += add;
  printf("Amount deposited %f\n", add);

}

void withdraw()
{
  int acc_num;
  float withdraw;
  char c;
  char s[100];

  // all checks ommitted!
  puts("Account to withdraw from: ");
  c = getc(stdin);
  getc(stdin);
  acc_num = (int) c - 48;
  puts("Amount to withdraw from account: ");
  fgets(s, 99, stdin);
  withdraw = atof(s);
  avail_bal[acc_num] -= withdraw;
  printf("Current balance for account %d: %f\n", acc_num, avail_bal[acc_num]);

}

void pexit()
{
  // place logic to save data here or use a function triggered by atexit() for that task
  puts("Imagine all of your data would have been put in a safe place!");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Just replace the constructs with `scanf` before you pass your work for grading.

Comment: just mentioning, using struct would be more understandable :)

Comment: So to replace scanf with fgets I would simply do scanf("%f", add) right? Also instead of getc(stdin) I could use getchar() too couldn't I? One other thing what's atof? Thank you

Comment: `fgets()` is different from `scanf()`; you can replace `getc()` with `getchar(stdin)`, both might be implemented as a macro, the function`fgetc()` is not; `atof()` is a simplifed version of `strof()`, the main difference is the lack of error-checking. You can get all this information in the man-pages. If you have none installed (e.g.: on windows) you can find them online e.g.: http://linux.die.net/man/ It is also a good idea to ask Google for examples, e.g.: `C atof example` and parse through the results.

Comment: Could I take away the atof and replace simply initialize at add=0 and withdraw =0? My compiler says possible loss of data

Comment: The `fgets()` gives you a string, you have to convert it to a number if you want to use it as a number. That's the reason I mentioned to replace all of these constructs with `scanf()` which does it for you. or you write a function yourself, that converts the string into a number. Doing it for integers is "simple", doing it for floats is **very** hard. But if I misunderstood you and you want just a placeholder, then go for it (but use `0.0` instead, should get rid of the warning, altgough I don't know you compiler very well).

Comment: Okay I understand one other thing, why is 99 used in the fgets?

Comment: You should be a tutor

Comment: 99 because 100 were reserved and `fgets()` adds a `\0` at the end. Oh and BTW: I should not be a tutor, I lack the patience.

Comment: You really should make a new question out of that if you had tried it yourself for some time. That would allow for a answer with nicely formatted code. Nevertheless, hints: allocate some memory `char *out` (`malloc()`), read individual characters from stdin (`getc()`), check if you have enough memory left (min. 4: user-input, "ut", `\0`) otherwise allocate some (`realloc()`), concatenate user-input to `out`, check if it is a vowel (loop over `char` array of vowels), if not: concatenate "ut". Rinse and repeat until end of user-input (e.g.: `\n` in Unix). Add a `\0`, print `out` to `stdout`.

Comment: I have a rough program I wrote based on some things you gave me but I'm honestly very lost, would you be willing to help me in chat (if this forum has a chat) sometime tomorrow? If not it's okay, not having a computer with a compiler besides at my college doesn't help me XD :(

Comment: I have posted two question regarding my issue and they were down voted...

Comment: stackoverflow has a chat, but I don't chat (I type waaaay too slow and am really bad at debugging per chat, makes me nervous). There are online-compilers, e.g.: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php which seems quite nice. It has an editor and a terminal below where you can use GCC to compile your code. I couldn't find any of your questions, did they get deleted or did you delete them?

Comment: I deleted them :/ I'll post my code on here in a little bit I've been using c shell but for this one I'm needing to create two files which no online compiler can likely do

Comment: The IDE I linked to allows for several files, just right-click (if you have a right-click) on the directory symbol in the left upper part. I don't know if they support makefiles, too, but for two files its just `gcc -W -Wall -std=c11 file1.c file2.c -o executablename`

Comment: Sweet thanks a lot, could I just change the value of each letter? Ex) b="but"

Comment: So this is the code I have roughly written on a c programming app XD can I send it in a message to you?

Comment: *sigh* ok, you can use my github adress.

Comment: Hahaha okay how? What is it

Comment: In my profile page there is a link to my github page and at the left of that github-page you'll find my email address (the GMX one). Sorry for the complications but I don't want to write it out here, I hope that's understandable. You can use a throw-away-adress (of the time restricted kind not the one-time one, because you want an answer, don't you? ;-) ) if you want, I don't filter them out.

Comment:  yes sir I'll send you what I have I may want an answer I'm really trying to understand how too though lol and yeah totally understand  thanks a million for your help

Comment: Didn't work. Did you tried the email adress starting with "czurnieden", and, after a dot (some call it period, point even) the three letter combination "gmx" followed by another dot and the TDL "de"?

Comment: Czurnieden.gmx.@de.com?

Comment: I haven't sent it yet cause I'm at work but I can't find it cause I'm on mobile!!

Comment: You are not very familiar with the stoneage  technology called "email", aren't you? Oh, I feel old now ;-) I jumbled it a bit but I thought it would be deciphable. It is czurnieden@gmx.de. Please be aware that the earth has a quite, although not fully spherical form (yes, I'm at a different timezone)

Comment: I was just confused by the @!! I didn't think about how you were in India lol I sent it let me know if you got it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using integer values as options why you are using character's

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[20];
float avail_bal;

void options();
void open();
void list();
void deposit();
void withdraw();
void exit();

int main(void)
{
        int option;
        printf("****Banking System WELCOME****\n");
        void options();
        printf("Enter 1-5 of the following options: \n");

        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: open();
            break;
            case 2: list();
            break;
            case 3: deposit();
            break;
            case 4: withdraw();
            break;
            case 5: return 0;
            default: exit();
            break;
        }

    return 0;
}

void options()
{
printf("1. Open Account\n");
printf("2. List Accounts\n");
printf("3. Deposit\n");
printf("4. Withdraw\n");
printf("5. Exit");
}

void open()
{
    float avail_bal = 0;
    char name[20];
    int acc_num;

    printf("Open new account(enter number 1-5)\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &acc_num);
    printf("Account number:     %d\n");
    printf("Available balance:      %f\n");
}

void list()
{
}

void deposit()
{
float add;
int acc_num;

printf("Which count do you want to deposit money in?");
scanf(" %d", &acc_num);
printf("Amount to deposit: ");
scanf("%f", &add);
while()
{
}
}
void withdraw()
{
int acc_num;
float withdraw;

printf("Account to withdraw from: ");
scanf("%d", &acc_num);
printf("Amount to withdraw from account: ")
scanf("%f", &withdraw);
while()
{
    printf("Current balance for account %d: %f ");
    break;
} acc_num++
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I'm a noob, do you mean in the int main? Void options is only to display menu

Comment: All I'm saying is if you want to take values from user between 1 to 5 you can simply use an integer as compare to constant.